# Halcon deep OCR detection training

Tags: deep-learning, ocr, halcon

In a Halcon deep OCR use-case for handwritten text,
I am having problems with the OCR **detection** phase.

Considering the low quality of my images the **recognition** of the text is quite acceptable after training. (using deep_ocr_recognition_training_workflow.hdev)

But no matter I use any of the pre-trained model or my own trained model, the **detection** remains the same. And it is not a matter of setting detection_min_word_score or detection_min_character_score because based on score maps some text is completely ignored and can't be catchd by lowering min scores as suggested [here](https://www.mvtec.com/services-support/developers-corner/article/deep-ocr-tips-and-tricks).

In the documentation for set_deep_ocr_param (get_deep_ocr_param ) it is stated that a parameter "detection_model" can be passed for detection mode. But I can't find how any clue what sort of data learning tool project can be used for this or how the model should be trained.

I mean the parameter detection_model is there. So where is the information on training such model?

I have tried passing the trained model with deep_ocr_recognition_training_workflow.hdev as the detection model but it detects the model type as **recognition** and shows an error that a model of **detection** type should be used.